# How do I get rid of redundant Wine launchers in Unity?

Tags: unity, wine, launcher, .desktop

[image]

I want to get rid of redundant Unity launchers of uninstalled software, especially uninstalled windows (wine) software. All answers already given elsewhere are user specific and not universal and does not work for me.

There are nowhere *wine-extensions* to be found, neither in root.

There are no *REAPER.desktop* or any of that sort to be found, neither in root.

No *REAPER.desktop* nowhere.

HOWEVER! When dragging a*emphasized text* redundant launcher from Unity to the desktop Linux creates a *REAPER.desktop* on the desktop. And this will be the ONLY **REAPER.desktop** file in the whole system.

Comment: Have you checked `/opt` folder ?

Comment: Looked in `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: Ok, now I did find wine-extensions there. Funny because searching by sudo `find / '*wine-extension*'` didn't render any results. Since I was confusing '~' for root then I must have confused other matters also. Problem solved? Thx!

Comment: *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Where Wine launchers are stored

Since `Wine` applications are installed inside `~/.Wine` (locally), `Wine` launchers are also created locally ***by definition***, in `~/.local/share/applications`. There simply is no other option then that these launchers are located there.

What can be misleading however is that the *filename* of a `.desktop` file does not necessarily show the *interface* name of the application, as it appears in Dash. To find out, you can make suspected launchers executable (in nautilus, right- click on the icon > properties). Once the file is executable, its icon will then show what they represent, and the displayed name will be according to the name in Dash.

Another option is to run:

```
grep -iR reaper ~/.local/share/applications/
```

To see which of the files contains your application's name.

#### N.B.

The `~` (tilde) stands for `/home/yourname`.  Note that `~/.local` is a *hidden* directory in your home folder. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while in nautilus, to make hidden directories visible.

Comment: Sounds cool, however I don't even have ~/.local/share/applications understanding ~ stands for root.

Comment: @user232365 What?  `~` stands for `/home/yourname`!

Comment: @user232365: No, `~` stands for your home directory: `/home/<username>`

Comment: Explains a lot. Thx.

Comment: Problem solved. I don't need anymore answers. Thx again Gunnar.

Comment: @user232365 *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.